Browser show 404 although response indicates 200 in Laravel
I've been working with Laravel since 2019, and recently started to refactor my main project which uses Laravel 7.x. One of the routes of this project allows to get the profile image of an Entity, accessing through this GET route https://{short}.domain.club/perfil.png, which passes the request to the function profileImage($short).
This function returns a PNG Image specifying a 200 HTTP response. However, the problem is that the browser marks it as a 404 response although the image is displayed. This only happens when working with my domain.club but not under domain.xyz.
To help analysis, I share the code of my function and two screenshots that evidence the problem.
public function profileImage($short) {
        $business = Business::where('shortname',$short)->first();
        if($business === null) $rawImage = 'https://dummyimage.com/180x180/ffffff/000000&text='.urlencode($short);
        elseif(!empty($business->imageprofile) && Storage::exists($business->imageprofile)) $rawImage = Storage::get($business->imageprofile);
        else $rawImage = $business->getDummyImageURL('180x180');
            
        $image = Image::make($rawImage);
        $encodedImage = $image->encode('png');
        $contentLength = strlen($encodedImage);
        return response($encodedImage, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/png')->header('Content-Length', $contentLength);
    }

Response 404: https://i.ibb.co/ydz9fCM/response-404.png
Response 200: https://i.ibb.co/2FnxYm9/response-200.png
The main difference between both NGINX configuration files is that domain.club includes this block of code.
gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level    5;
    gzip_min_length    256;
    gzip_proxied       any;
    gzip_vary          on;

    gzip_types
    application/atom+xml
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/ld+json
    application/manifest+json
    application/rss+xml
    application/vnd.geo+json
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    application/x-font-ttf
    application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    application/xhtml+xml
    application/xml
    font/opentype
    image/bmp
    image/svg+xml
    image/x-icon
    text/cache-manifest
    text/css
    text/plain
    text/vcard
    text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
    text/vtt
    text/x-component
    text/x-cross-domain-policy;
    # text/html is always compressed by gzip module

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
        expires 7d;
    }

Finally, I have to mention that my deployment code in Forge includes this line to restart FPM.
echo 'Restarting FPM...'; sudo -S service $FORGE_PHP_FPM reload ) 9>/tmp/fpmlock

Hope you can help me finding a way to look for the cause of this malfunction.
I've added 'Content-Type' and 'Content-Length' to Header hoping this could solve the problem, but it didn't work.
